# Meteor + Reactjs: Incoming Token Parameter

Tags: reactjs, meteor, parameters, token

My application has functionality to send an invitation to create an account.

The link is created and sent using a server side method, the invitationId stored in a collection.

```
> ${Meteor.absoluteUrl(`accept-invite/${invitationId}`)}

> http://myapp.com/accept-invite/emwwKwZkjhWE5KrYs
```

This works good. Navigation to the accept-invite page is successful (React Router v4)

My error says `params is undefined` as I can not seem to grab **invitiationId** "*emwwKwZkjhWE5KrYs*" or token upon loading the accept-invite/:token

My accept-invite page withTracker

```
export default withTracker(({ params }) => {
  const invitationId = params.token;
  const subscription = Meteor.subscribe('invitations.accept', invitationId);
  return{
    loading: !subscription.ready(),
    invitation: Invitations.findOne(invitationId),
};
})(AcceptInvitation);
```

my error is params is undefined, invitation_id / token value is not being assigned any upon loading my accept-invite page, stumping myself because I feel I am missing a piece of logic!

Comment: Aren't route parameters usually accessed with `props.match.params.token` ?

Comment: Yes thank you! this worked for me. export default withTracker(({match}) => {
  const invitationId = match.params.token.replace('=','');

Comment: Please give me an uptick on the comment :)

Answer (score 0):

The above and first comment worked for me.

```
export default withTracker(({match}) => {  
 const invitationId = match.params.token.replace('=','');
```

this let me take incoming parameter defined as a `:/token` in React Router v4 (Meteor)

```
example http://maddog.com/accept-invite/:=youthebest
```

invitation id is equal to `youthebest`